# Huge established number of socket in activemq

Tags: java, sockets, activemq-classic

I am having issue in which there is huge number of established sockets with activemq.

According to ActiveMQ document, the socket will be closed due to inactivity. But in my application, after sometime, I have a huge socket connections due to inactivity. Here is my settings:

**Client configuration** is having soTimeout 30s, connectionTimeout 10s

**Broker Configuration** is having maxInactivityDuration as 30s

In the log file, I am having the below exception, but I am unable to understand why socket is not closed as per activemq documentation.

> [WARN ] [20/Nov/17 23:58:06.473] [Transport] - Transport Connection
>   to: tcp://10.227.129.219:34896 failed:
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Channel was
>   inactive (no connection attempt made) for too (>30000) long:
>   tcp://10.227.129.219:34896

Active mq documentation is mentioned [here](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-inactivitymonitor.html)

> Using the default values; if no data has been written or read from the
>   connection for 30 seconds, the InactivityMonitor kicks in. The
>   InactivityMonitor throws an InactivityIOException and shuts down the
>   transport associated with the connection

For your information, I am using activemq 5.13.3. Below is the snapshot of `netstat` command.

```
netstat -an | grep 9999
tcp        0      0 X.X.X.X:9999           Y.Y.Y.Y:38200        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 X.X.X.X:9999           Y.Y.Y.Y:44582        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 X.X.X.X:9999           Y.Y.Y.Y:41278        ESTABLISHED
... (few hundreds in total)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what mean by inactivity? Is the application not responding(so their is good tcp connection (like socket is good and application freeze)but application timing out)? Or is like a network problem and the tcp connection itself messes up? So if you wanted to conserve network, you can close sockets with no application data sent but still tcp keep alive.

Comment: "Using the default values; if no data has been written or read from the connection for 30 seconds, the InactivityMonitor kicks in. The InactivityMonitor throws an InactivityIOException and shuts down the transport associated with the connection"

Comment: That comment serves no purpose in helping you find answer

Comment: Oh it was not there in original question, so i edited the question with blockquote from activemq documentation. My concern is about InactivityMonitor process, as it already kicked off, the associated socket should be closed as well. However, sockets are still in established stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the log file that you shared, TCP handshake was done, then activemq protocol (application level) is waiting for connection to be established. Due to any issue (e.g. network connection, etc), the connection cannot be established. I am guessing that your tcp keeplive configuration is enabled. Hence, TCP connections are not closed, and application (e.g. activemq) didn't close it either.

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved issue, you mentioned some of the correct points.

Comment: If TCP keepalive was enabled the connection *would* be closed, or rather reset. It doesn't actually 'keep' connections 'alive', despite its name, it detects dead ones. Eventually.